# Pandas: condense survey results

Tags: python, pandas

I have survey results that have the following format:

```
   Lab Shepherd Poodle Frisky Sleepy Hungry
0  NaN      NaN    Yes    Yes    NaN    NaN
1  Yes      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    Yes
2  NaN      Yes    NaN    NaN    Yes    NaN
```

I would like to transform my dataframe to the following:

```
      Breed Disposition
0    Poodle      Frisky
1       Lab      Hungry
2  Shepherd      Sleepy
```

What is the most effective way to accomplish this?
Groupby?  Pivot?

Is there any advantage to replacing every instance of 'Yes' with 'True' and use Boolean tests?

Thanks in advance.  DataFrame code follows, for ease of answering.

```
d = [['', '','Yes','Yes','',''],['Yes', '','','','','Yes'],['','Yes','','','Yes','']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d,columns=['Lab','Shepherd','Poodle','Frisky','Sleepy','Hungry'])
df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True, inplace = True)
```

Comment: There are only `True`s and `''` values?

Comment: My raw data has the values 'Select' or ' ' (space).  I converted the spaces to NaN's to make it easier to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and create new `DataFrame` by `groupby` with `list` and `DataFrame` constructor:

```
a = df.stack().reset_index().groupby('level_0')['level_1'].apply(list)
df = pd.DataFrame(a.values.tolist())
```

Another solution is convert to `bool` - empty spaces are `False`s and for each row create list, last use `DataFrame` constructor too:

```
a = df.astype(bool).apply(lambda x: x.index[x].values.tolist(), axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(a.values.tolist())
```

---

```
df = df.astype(bool).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.index[x].values), axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
          0       1
0    Poodle  Frisky
1       Lab  Hungry
2  Shepherd  Sleepy
```

Comment: While both work, I particularly like the astype(bool) approach.  Many thanks - I've learned a lot from your other answers here on SO!

Comment: @BorealCoder - glad can help!

Answer (score 1):

There is another one

```
pd.DataFrame([df.columns.values[x] for x in df.notnull().values])
Out[145]: 
          0       1
0    Poodle  Frisky
1       Lab  Hungry
2  Shepherd  Sleepy
```

Comment: This has excellent readability.  Is there an advantage to this approach as the size of the df increases?  Thx Wen.

Comment: @BorealCoder Do not getting sacred by for loop , sometime they are faster than vectorize function when your df size is increase